# Create multi-dimensinal ArrayList in java

Tags: java

I want to create an arrayList as following.

```
id->1512   associated with the values -> 12,45,78
id->1578   associated with the values -> 456,78,87,96
```

What I have to do? Should I create a 2-d arrayList or can I do that with single dimension arraylist?

Comment: You need a `MultiMap<Integer, Integer>` (e.g. from Guava), or a `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>>
```

Comment: I'd prefer a [`MultiMap<Integer, Integer>`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: I prefer not using third party libraries

Comment: @Aubin: Why not? A `MultiMap` will result in much nicer code, as you don't have to `null` check every key.

Comment: @jlordo thanks, but never really used Guava library before .. :P. but sounds like a good one :)

Comment: @PremGenError: Compare the code in my answer to what would be needed to add the key/value pairs to your `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Guava Library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), and you can do this for your associations:

```
Multimap<Integer, Integer> map = HashMultimap.create();
map.putAll(1512, Arrays.asList(12, 45, 78));
map.putAll(1578, Arrays.asList(456, 78, 87, 96));
```

Here's an example how you can get the values:

```
int key = 1512;
for (Integer value : map.get(key)) {
    System.out.println("Associated " + key + " -> " + value);
}
```

Here's a link to Guava's [JavaDoc](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/index.html)

Comment: @Aubin: Sorry, I can't understand what your comment means in regard to my answer.

Comment: Occam's razor says you have to adapt means to goals. Guava is over sized for this simple problem. Dependencies reduces the re-usability of a solution.

Comment: @Aubin: Ok, makes sense now. In this case, we have to agree to disagree, because Guava makes programming this kind of map so much easier. You don't have to `null` check when inserting, you don't have to think about what kind of collection is used to save the values and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need ArrayList. read abut [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)